# Check if variable is being modified within a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, error-handling

My code:

```
public int Position
{
    get
    {
        return position;
    }
    private set
    {
        position = value;
    }
}
```

Currently 'Position' cannot be modified outside the class.

When I do

```
MyClass.Position = 1
```

Visual Studio gives me the error `The property or indexer 'MyClass.Position' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible`. Is there a way to change the code such that I can check if the variable is being modified within the class or outside of class and `throw new InvalidOperationException` if the variable is being changed outside of the class?

I want to throw the error myself instead of Visual Studio stopping me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not without a lot of hackyness. That's not how the language works. What are you trying to achieve by this? You can make it so that any access of the property throw the exception always, and then just access through the private field within the class.

Comment: I don't see the point of your request. If you don't want a variable to be modified, declare it as `readonly`. If you don't want a property to be modified, use a getter-only property or a property with an `init` setter. Declaring a member as modifiable but then throwing an exception when an attempt is made to modify it makes no sense.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to not do that. If your public api provides a read- only property, then have a ro- property. You still can mutate the backing field from within. Faking read-write and then throw on access would be an anti pattern in my book. Unless you have a _very_ good reason to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a "internal_set" flag and set to true when you set value internally.

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        private int position;
        private bool internal_set = false;
        public int Position 
        {
            get
            {
                return position;
            }
            set
            {
                if (internal_set)
                {
                    position = value;
                    internal_set = false;    //set flag back to false;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }
        public void set()
        {
            internal_set = true;  //You need set the flag to true before set value;
            Position = 1;
        }
    }
```